# laravel phpunit - get() method not defined

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to use `phpunit` within Laravel 5.6 and getting this error:

```
$ phpunit

1) Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::testBasicTest
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\ExampleTest::get()

/Users/xxxx/dev/xxxx/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php:12
```

My code at `tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
  public function testBasicTest()
  {
    $response = $this->get('/');
    $response->assertStatus(200);
  }
}
```

My code at `tests/TestCase.php`

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
  public function setUp():void { parent::setUp(); }
  public function tearDown():void { parent::tearDown(); }
  use CreatesApplication;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Undo your commented-out extension. The base PHPUnit testcase lacks the laravel convenience functions provided by illuminate's testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user said, you are using the base PHPUnit class, you must be using the Laravel class because it adds stuff for testing... so your code should be like this:

```php
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
  public function setUp():void { parent::setUp(); }
  public function tearDown():void { parent::tearDown(); }
  use CreatesApplication;
}
```

---

And please, do lint/format your code, follow standards...

```php
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
}
```

Here, there is no need to overwrite `setUp` and `tearDown` because you are calling the parent, that is exactly the same as not defining them on this file...

Comment: thanks for the answer. by using laravel testcase I'm getting this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815737/laravel-phpunit-testcase-setup-and-teardown-must-be-compatible-with-phpuni